# Angular 5 service unit test with http async

Tags: angular

I have the following service

```
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    login(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(environment.url.login, {'username': email, 'password': password}, {})
        .map(async (loginRequest) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (loginRequest && loginRequest.token) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', loginRequest.token);
            }
            return loginRequest.token;
        })
        .pipe(retry(0));
    }
}
```

And I want to write a unit test for that. I have come so far:

```
describe('AuthenticationService', () => {
    let httpClientSpy;
    let authenticationService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        // Create a fake HttpClient object with a `post()` spy
        httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['post']);

        authenticationService = new AuthenticationService(<any> httpClientSpy);

        // bypass localstorage functions to mockLockalStorage
        spyOn(localStorage, 'removeItem')
            .and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.removeItem);
        spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem')
            .and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.getItem);
    });

    it('#login should return observable of token', (done) => {
        httpClientSpy.post.and.returnValue(of({token}));

        const login = authenticationService.login('Username', '123489');
        expect(httpClientSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); 

        // todo: check return value

        done();
    });
});
```

This results in an Error:  : Expected a spy, but got Object({ post: spy on HttpClient.post }).

Ignoring the `expect(httpClientSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();`

```
    it('#login should return observable of token', (done) => {
        httpClientSpy.post.and.returnValue(of({token}));

        const login = authenticationService.login('Username', '123489');

        login.subscribe(response => {
            expect(response).toBe(of({token}));
        });

        done();
    });
});
```

results in a: Expected [object Promise] to be ScalarObservable

I have seen so may different unit tests using mocks and spys and injecting services in every "it(...)", I have read the testing chapters from Angular, but I just don't understand how this should work. Please help me.

Comment: First test, try `expect(httpClientSpy('post']).toHaveBeenCalled()`. Second test, try `expect(response).toEqual(of({token}));`

Comment: https://medium.com/netscape/testing-with-the-angular-httpclient-api-648203820712 explains in detail

Comment: @trichetriche `expect(httpClientSpy['post']).toHaveBeenCalled()` works, thank you!
`expect(response).toEqual(of({token}));` results in a `Expected [object Promise] to equal ScalarObservable[...]`